# Eclipse: Altering preferences at startup

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, preferences

I'm working on an Eclipse plugin that has a preference page, the `performOk()` method of which alters preferences of a few other plugins to accommodate the changes. Works nicely so far.

However, if the user changes the prefs file of my plugin manually or updates the plugin, he has to go to the preferences page and press "OK" manually, otherwise the other plugin's preferences will be out of date.

I would like to avoid this problem by adjusting the other plugins' preferences on each start of Eclipse. I've made my plugin class implement the `IStartup` interface and its `earlyStartup()` method to alter the preferences there, but I have two problems with that:

1. I need to read a setting from my own plugin before altering the preferences of the other ones, but the `getPreferenceStore()` method does not work within the `earlyStartup()` method. I was able to work around this by implementing `earlyStartup()` empty and doing what I want in the plugin's `start()` method, is this behaviour reliable?
2. I get *Invalid thread access* exceptions when actually altering the preferences in the `start()` method. I've read that `start()` is executed by its own job, can jobs change preferences?

If there is an alternative way to achieve what I want, I'd naturally also like to know.

Comment: User's who update plugin preferences manually should not expect reasonable behavior.  I would argue that that situation is not something that you need to handle.

Comment: I guess I don't really understand what you are trying to do and why updating your plugin will affect the preferences of other plugins.

Comment: @Andrew Eisenberg: Well, the users might not manually change things, but they could import a preferences file for instance. My plugin (http://github.com/fhd/eclipse-color-theme) changes the color preferences of several editors, JDT etc.

Comment: Sounds like a great plugin.  I might try it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your main concern is that someone is importing some changes from some exported eclipse preferences file, then you should be able to solve the problem by using a preference changed listener.  This would handle the situation you mention above.  If preferences change through Eclipse and while eclipse is open, then your preference changed listener will be activated.

I have never heard of anyone manually editing their preference files outside of eclipse (this is the one situation that a preference changed listener will not catch).  And if someone does, they shouldn't expect reliable behavior.

However, if you really do want to use IEarlyStartup, you can, but you should use a Display.synchExec() to execute the preference changing code.  See: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/preferences/AbstractPreferenceInitializer.html

Comment: Hm, but this would not be invoked when my plugin is updated, would it? Updating doesn't change the preferences.

Comment: The whole earlyStartup() thing is working now, thanks! I'll accept your answer because it works, but I would also be interested in whether you can think of a better way to handle the updating, I don't feel well doing this.

Comment: Hmm...performing an action when after an update is tricky.  There is no built-in mechanism to do this.  What I have done before is stored the fully qualified version number of a plugin in the Eclipse preferences.  On startup, do a check to see if the stored version matches the current version.  If not, then you know that an upgrade has occurred and you can do whatever magic you need.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a good idea! I can then display a message box, asking whether the user wants to re-apply the skin! I will use this in conjunction with a preference change listener and it should be allright.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension point `org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences`.  You can use this to set the default values for any preference in your plugin's preference store.  You may be able to use this extension point to set preferences in other plugins and this may be some way that you can get around the problem that you are having.

Comment: This is apparently only executed when I go to the plugin's preferences page, not after Eclipse starts.

Comment: Actually, more precisely, when using a PreferenceInitializer, the initializeDefaultPreferences method is "called automatically by the preference initializer when the appropriate default preference node is accessed."  (See: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/preferences/AbstractPreferenceInitializer.html).  Now, that I understand better what you are trying to do, you actually don't want to set "Default" preferences.  It's a little tricky because you want to override the preferences that other plugins control.